# How to (automatically) create a mock object for an interface from an object of a class implementing that interface?

Tags: java, mocking

well I have an interface called InputInterface, which has some get methods. I also have a complex gui class, which implements that InputInterface, now since it's too complicated to serialize that whole class and it extends and implements more interfaces, I'd like to create something like a mock object, which would create something like a copy of the answers that my complex class gives out at the current moment.

I wanted to create a class implementing that interface, which would hold the values, but then I realized this should be a standard procedure for things like EasyMock or other mocking libs? Just how can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually instantiate an interface, specifying the required methods.

```
MyInterface myInterface = new MyInterface() {
    public void requiredMethod(...) {
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: What would I save here then? I still have to implement something here. I would rather implement a Mocker which would perform what I was asking for, but I believe it's probably implemented in these Mock libraries or other libraries already, so I don't want to reimplement the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

Mockito provides a "spy" mechanism to wrap an existing object and thereby be able to observe method calls and potentially stub individual method calls. However, it does not provide a mechanism to cache the first call to the spied object and then continuously return this value.

[Mockito - see the section of "Spy of real object"](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

I found this via a google search of "Mockito spy cache". It seems like it might do the trick.

[Mockito caching-spy](https://github.com/ManuelB/mockito-caching-spy)

Comment: Hmm, well in this case, exactly what I would need would be somethinig that would cache it, or do a copy of the answers of the methods, because observing might break this down I believe. But there has to be some lib or framework which would do that hmm. Maybe it's not related to mocking, though sounds similar, but still.